# Number the algorithms with itemize or other environment

Tags: numbering, itemize, algorithms

I am trying to number the two `algorithm` environments and put some space between each other but I am just getting the numeration at the side? How can I manage it to get the number before the algorithms?

[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{german,t1enc}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[1.]

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{2 graphs  T and \'{T} with nodes V and \'{V}.}
\KwResult{Find whether T and \'{T} are isomorph.}

function(T, \'{T}) \\
\Indp Find  bijection of $\forall v \in V$ with $v_1, v_2  \dots , v_k$ in T so that $\pi(v)$ has the following childern $\pi(v_1), \pi(v_2), \dots, \pi(v_n)$ in \'{T}; \\
\If{the bijection is permutation}{
  T and \'{T} are isomorph;
}
\end{algorithm}

\item[2.]

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{2 graphs  T and \'{T} with nodes V and \'{V}.}
\KwResult{Find whether T and \'{T} are isomorph.}

function(T, \'{T}) \\
\Indp Find  bijection of $\forall v \in V$ with $v_1, v_2  \dots , v_k$ in T so that $\pi(v)$ has the following childern $\pi(v_1), \pi(v_2), \dots, \pi(v_n)$ in \'{T}; \\
\If{the bijection is permutation}{
  T and \'{T} are isomorph;
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to load `t1enc` explicitly. And `enumerate` would --- enumerate --- your item list ;-)

Comment: Why not using `algorithms` package ? [documentation](http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf)
Algorithms are automatically numbered like all other floatting objects.

Comment: @JérômeDequeker: The `algorithm2e` package allows for chapter/sectionwise numbering too, but I don't know why the O.P. want's to have them in a list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place a `\mbox{}` before the algorithm environments (after each `\item`)

The `itemize` environment should be replaced by `enumerate` which provides the numbering instead of `\item[1.]` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{german,t1enc} % Is this needed?
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \mbox{}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{2 graphs  T and \'{T} with nodes V and \'{V}.}
\KwResult{Find whether T and \'{T} are isomorph.}

function(T, \'{T}) \\
\Indp Find  bijection of $\forall v \in V$ with $v_1, v_2  \dots , v_k$ in T so that $\pi(v)$ has the following childern $\pi(v_1), \pi(v_2), \dots, \pi(v_n)$ in \'{T}; \\
\If{the bijection is permutation}{
  T and \'{T} are isomorph;
}
\end{algorithm}

\item \mbox{}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{2 graphs  T and \'{T} with nodes V and \'{V}.}
\KwResult{Find whether T and \'{T} are isomorph.}

function(T, \'{T}) \\
\Indp Find  bijection of $\forall v \in V$ with $v_1, v_2  \dots , v_k$ in T so that $\pi(v)$ has the following childern $\pi(v_1), \pi(v_2), \dots, \pi(v_n)$ in \'{T}; \\
\If{the bijection is permutation}{
  T and \'{T} are isomorph;
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]